Error after securing update dml: INVALID_FIELD, Cannot specify both an external ID reference fieldxyz__r and a Salesforce id, fieldxyz__c
I retrieve a record with SOQL:
Asset assetRecord = [SELECT Id, fieldxyz__c, fieldxyz__r.Name FROM Asset WHERE Id = :someId WITH USER_MODE LIMIT 1];

At some point, I update this record and it works:
update assetRecord;

Now, if I secure this DML update:
update as user assetRecord;

An exception is thrown:

INVALID_FIELD, Cannot specify both an external ID reference
fieldxyz__r and a salesforce id, fieldxyz__c: []

I don't understand why it happens with secured DMLs but normal DMLs just works. Can someone explain it to me why this happens? And what is the most efficient way to bypass this error?
I created a new Asset and only put the fields I want to update and its solved, but I wish to know if there is a better way or something to consider.
Thank you!

In "normal" DML,, does it really work? fieldxyz__c and fieldxyz__r is a circular reference.
